# Stubbing a method of tested class with Minitest

Tags: ruby, minitest

I am writing a part of larger framework and I have problems with stubbing. Here is what I have

```
class A
    def bar
        # some code
        foo
        # some code
    end
    def foo
        # method dependent on other parts of the framework
    end
end
```

Now I want to test the method bar, but it depends on foo and foo calls other parts of the framework (which is more a matter of integration testing). What I would like to do is to stub foo in my test, something like:

```
class TestA < Minitest::Test
    def stubbed_foo
        return 5
    end
    def test_bar
        a = A.new
        # use stubbed_foo in a instead of foo
        result = a.bar 
        # some assert
    end
end
```

But I don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think if I understand correctly you are looking for [MiniTest::Object#stub](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/minitest/4.2.0/Object:stub)

```
def test_bar
    a = A.new
    # use stubbed_foo in a instead of foo
    a.stub :foo, 5 do 
      result = a.bar 
      # some assert
    end
end
```

Here is a full example:

```
require 'minitest/autorun'

class A 
    def bar
        foo + 1
    end
    def foo 
        3
    end
end

class TestA < MiniTest::Unit::TestCase

    def test_bar
        a = A.new
        a.stub :foo, 5 do 
            result = a.bar
            assert_equal(6,result)
        end
    end

  def test_actual_bar
    a = A.new
    result = a.bar
    assert_equal(4,result)
  end
end
```

**Update: Based on Comment how to return multiple values**

```
class A 
  def bar
    foo + 1
  end
  def foo 
    3
  end
end

class TestA < MiniTest::Unit::TestCase

  def test_bar
    a = A.new
    stubbed_foo = [5,7].to_enum
    a.stub :foo, ->{stubbed_foo.next} do  
      assert_equal(6,a.bar)
      assert_equal(8,a.bar)
    end
  end

  def test_actual_bar
    a = A.new
    assert_equal(4,a.bar)
  end
end
```

Comment: That is precisely what i was looking for. Now what if bar called foo two times and I wanted the stub to return different values on every call? E.g. stub it, so it returns 5 on the first call of foo and 7 on its second call?

Comment: @VáclavPruner see update. You just need a callable object to return the expected values. In this case I used a `lambda` and `Enumerator#next` to handle the request